# Adding a centered "loading..." message inside the progress bar

Tags: javascript, html

How can the code below be modified such that I would be able to add a centered "loading..." message inside the box while the progress bar runs in the background? Ie. it would display LOADING..." in the center of the box while the progress bar runs in the background inside the DIV.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript">  
var prg_width = 200;  
var progress_run_id = null; 

function progress() {  
var node = document.getElementById('progress');  
    var w  = node.style.width.match(/\d+/);

    if (w == prg_width) {  
        clearInterval( progress_run_id ); 
        w = 0;
        alert("done")
    } else { 
        w = parseInt(w) + 5 + 'px';          
    } 
    node.style.width = w; 
}

function runit() { 
    progress_run_id = setInterval(progress, 30); 
} 

</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
        <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; width:200px; height:20px;">  
        <div id="progress" style="height:20px; width:0px; background-color:#DBDBDB;"/>  
        </div>  
        </div>
        <p><a href="javascript:runit()">Start</a></p>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; width:200px; height:20px;">  
    <div id="progress" style="text-align: center; height:20px; width:0px; background-color:#DBDBDB;"/>

    <div style="  position: fixed;   left: 92px ">loading</div>


    </div>  
    </div>
```